Managed App Configuration in MAUI for MDMs (InTune, MiraDore etc)
We distribute a managed android version of our mobile app to several large customers for their MDMs. This lets them control the roll out to hundreds of devices. The MDMs in play currently are InTune and Miradore. Whilst InTune has an SDK, Miradore does not. However, both allow for app configuration through their UIs. The IT teams want to make use of this with our app so they can preset an API URL, app default settings etc when the app runs without relying on the users to do this, or having to handle each device themselves.
What I'm struggling with is documentation to guide us around where we configure this in MAUI when building our app. To essentially define/enable the various settings within our app that we will allow the MDM to configure. Our ideal is that we don't need to use the InTune SDK, and then another solution for MiraDore and so on.
Searching google, MAUI documentation, and the documentation from the various MDMs.

Refer to https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration?WT.mc_id=friends-0000-jamont&ref=montemagno.com (as you can see from configuration sources it includes MDMs) as a new way to do it.
I have also had luck building everything myself from scratch to get higher freedom and control.
I used platform specific apis to get key-value pairs configured through mdm for iOS and Android and then built an interface to access it app wide.
Idea: I created a source generator to create class from the mdm file (containing key value pairs), populating it and making it easier to access.
